# Examples of open, closed, non-open, non-closed, clopen and non-open and non-closed

Tags: general-topology

I'm familiar with open and closed sets.
Open sets are those where you can draw some open ball in every of its points, in such a way that the ball will be in the set. Closed sets are said to be so if its complement is open.
The main examples are (0,1) for open and [0,1] for closed.

But could you give two simple distinct examples on $\mathbb{R}$ of non-open and non-closed sets? I think it will help me to clarify these ideas.

Comment: what about $[0,1)$ ?

Comment: An important example is the set $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$S_1=(0,1)$ is open,
$S_2=[0,1]$ is closed,
$S_3=[0,1)$ and $S_4=(0,1]$ are neither open nor closed,

$S=\{n \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{n}\}$ is neither open nor closed (Why?).

Try to think $S=\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q^c}$ both are neither open nor closed,
Where $\mathbb{Q^c}$ is a set of irrational numbers.

Comment: Just a question: instead of $(0,1)$, I have learned the notation $]0,1[$, is that internationally accepted?

Comment: @Dominique That notation is internationally understood, but I believe less common outside France. See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/142/why-is-american-and-french-notation-different-for-open-intervals-x-y-vs-x for some discussion and further links.

Comment: @ronno oh yeah, I have edited my answers.

Comment: @StudentofMathematics thanks! But if a set in not open, is it also not closed? "Not open" and "not closed" are two different words for the same thing?

Comment: @ViníciusHector No, Not open does not imply not closed, and vice versa.

Comment: @StudentofMathematics could you think in a simple example of set that is not open, but isn't non-closed? (sorry for the repetition of negation).